# Word for an organization formed from a collapsed one?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was looking for a word that could be used in the context of "(organization 1) and its __________ organization, (organization 2)" that means 'created by members of the first organization with similar ideas when the first organization was destroyed'. I already saw subsidiary, but that wasn't quite what I was looking for, since the first organization did not survive the creation of the new one. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

`Spin-off` is one possibility commonly used. In business, one `leverages` one's experience to create something new.

But if you are looking at metaphorical terms 'caldera' come to mind.

> A caldera is a cauldron-like volcanic feature usually formed by the
>   collapse of land following a volcanic eruption.

Phenix is another:

> A Phoenix is a unique bird in classical mythology that lived for five
>   or six centuries in the Arabian desert, after this time burning itself
>   on a funeral pyre and rising from the ashes with renewed youth to live
>   through another cycle.

Comment: [*A “**phoenix company**” is a company that, at the time before or within five years after the commencement of liquidation of a failed company, is known by the same or a similar name as the failed company.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+phoenix+company+is+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) There are two separate "definitions" for what *Palmer's company law* drily identifies as "colloquial language". It works for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers amusing that that is actually a term.

Answer (score 2):

There is a legal concept of *[successor](http://definitions.uslegal.com/s/successor/)* that often is applied to organizations

> A successor is a person or entity who takes over and continues the role or position of another.
>
> and
>
> A corporate successor is a corporation that takes on the burdens of a previous corporation through merger, acquisition, or other means of succession.

*USLegal.com*

Similarly, one of *Macmillan's* definition of *[successor](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/successor)* is

> used about something such as an organization or machine that replaces something that did the same job before
>   *The Russian Federal Security Service is the main successor to the KGB.*

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[newco](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/newco)***  is the term generally used, though it does not necessarily imply that the old company is no longer existing.

> - (business) ***A new company, especially one spun-off from or replacing an existing company*** as a legal fiction to maintain ownership over an entity while separating it from the old company financially.

(wiktionary)

Comment: I would reserve *newco* for firms which are formed or re-formed by the owners of the previous firm; for example, General Motors Company LLC is the newco for General Motors Corporation (its bankrupt forebear, which still exists, with all its bad debts, as the Motors Liquidation Company). In contrast, Eastern AIr Lines Group has basically nothing to do with Eastern Air Lines Inc., besides the trademarks it has accumulated. It is a namesake, not a newco. Still, +1 for plucking out this term.

Answer (score 0):

[**Offshoot**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/offshoot) could be used. [Oxford]

> a thing that develops from something, especially a small organization that develops from a larger one

It's true that it doesn't imply the parent company is gone, but it also doesn't strongly imply that the parent is still there, like [subsidiary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/subsidiary) does.

Comment: This doesn't have any of the implication that the parent company is gone, though. It seems like the question is looking for something like a phoenix... risen from the ashes of the previous iteration.

Comment: @Catija: See edit

Answer (score 0):

You could apply ***reincarnate*** to your sample usage:

> Reborn in another body:
>   '*he claims that the girl is his dead daughter **reincarnate***'
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reincarnate)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Rump** works under some circumstances.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rump):

> 3
>   :  a small or inferior remnant or offshoot; especially :  a group (as a parliament) carrying on in the name of the original body after the departure or expulsion of a large number of its members

Happens to countries too: [List of rump states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rump_states).